# WPF C#. Происходит ошибка во внешнем коде. Почему так получается и как исправить?

Tags: c#, wpf

Описал в XAML `DataGrid`, указал метод при загрузке `Loaded="DataGrid_LoadTestData"`. Метод выполняется, но после него где-то во внешнем коде происходит ошибка. Однако, если закомментировать последнюю строчку метода то всё работает. Чем это объясняется?

Вообще цель моего теста понять как правильнее обновлять данные в таблице...
Если можно посоветуйте как правильно обновить большой объём данных (около 1000 строк).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DumpDataGrid" Loaded="DataGrid_LoadTestData">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- описал колонки -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Связанный метод при загрузке:

```
public struct DumpDataItem {
    UInt16 Adresss { get; set; };
    UInt32 AsInt { get; set; }
    float AsFloat => BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(AsInt),0);

    public DumpDataItem (UInt16 adresss, UInt32 data) {
        Adresss = adresss;
        AsInt = data;
    }
}

List<DumpDataItem> DataItemStorage = new List<DumpDataItem>();

void DataGrid_LoadTestData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    DumpDataItem[] testData = GetTestData();
    DataItemStorage.AddRange(testData);
    DumpDataGrid.ItemsSourse = DataItemStorage;
    DumpDataItem[] testData = GetTestData();
    DataItemStorage.AddRange(testData); // <=== Вот эту строчку
}
```

Comment: Что за ошибка-то?

Comment: @АндрейNOP в том то и дело, что VS нигде не пишет что за ошибка, а просто говорит, что произошла ошибка во внешнем коде! (p.s. ! - крик души)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно в отдельный список забрать все 1000 строк.
Допустим это персоны list, то будет отдельный класс для них куда и забираем все что нас интересует,  Вывод будет перебор списка и добавление элемента в DataGrid

Пример

```
//код содержит глупости, но показывает как заполнить DataGrid

 class Servers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
List<Servers> result = new List<Servers>();
var tempList = GetServer;

foreach (var currentserver in tempList)
                {
                 //тут возможно применить сортировку
                  result.Add(currentserver);
                }
ServerGrid.ItemsSource = result ;
```